# SessionHandlerInterface write method not being called

Tags: php

So I have created a class implementing SessionhandlerInterface and set it as a session handler:

```
$sessionHandler = new SessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($sessionHandler);
session_start();
```

The problem is, the write function is never called.

If I use the second parameter of session_set_save_handler and set it to false:

```
session_set_save_handler($sessionHandler, false);
```

Then it works properly. Can somebody explain this behaviour to me? I am using PHP 5.4.6.

In the documentation there is written:

> When using objects as session save handlers, it is important to register the shutdown function with PHP to avoid unexpected side-effects from the way PHP internally destroys objects on shutdown and may prevent the write and close from being called. Typically you should register 'session_write_close' using the register_shutdown_function() function.

As of PHP 5.4.0 you can use session_register_shutdown() or simply use the 'register shutdown' flag when invoking session_set_save_handler() using the OOP method and passing an instance that implements SessionHandlerInterface.

But I don't fully understand that.

Comment: What is the implementation of `SessionHandler`?

Comment: How about when you call `session_write_close()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#refsect1-function.session-set-save-handler-parameters) states the following:

> The "write" handler is not executed until after the output stream is
>   closed. Thus, output from debugging statements in the "write" handler
>   will never be seen in the browser. If debugging output is necessary,
>   it is suggested that the debug output be written to a file instead.

This is probably why you don't see the function being called if you use a simple `echo`.

Comment: thank you for referring to this line in doc of `session_set_save_handler`. in doc of `write`, this is not mentioned...